# Join two tables in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, join, pivot

I am taking an advanced Google sheet course and I got the following assignment.

I have a first table in Google Sheet (let's call it T1) with two variables, company name and salesman. For each company name there may be one or several salesmen. If there is more than one salesman for each company, then the table has multiple rows. For instance, in the table below, company C1 has two salesmen, while others have one only:

| Company | Salesman |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | S1 |
| C1 | S2 |
| C2 | S1 |
| C3 | S1 |

This is a mapping table.

I have a second table (let's call it T2) which has only the company names (C1, C2, C3, etc.) and other metadata referred to that company (O1, O2, O3, etc.). So even if there are multiple salesmen for a company, in table T2, there is only one entry for each company and its metadata (i.e., one row), like in the below:

| Company | Other |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | O1 |
| C2 | O2 |
| C3 | O3 |

I want to create a third table, T3, which expands T2 to accomodate the multiple salesmen. In other words, if in T2 there is C1 which has two salesmen, i.e. S1 and S2, I want the T2 to add a second row for C1, so that both salesmen can be correctly captured:

| Company | Other | Salesman |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | O1 | S1 |
| C1 | O1 | S2 |
| C2 | O2 | S1 |
| C3 | O3 | S1 |

How can I do this? Any Google Sheet or VBA answer would be much appreciated. I believe in SQL this would be achieved via some join/pivoting, but I am not sure in Google Sheet.

Answer (score 2):

**Excel ms365:**

[image]

Formula in `G1`:

```
=LET(x,A1:A5,HSTACK(x,VLOOKUP(x,D1:E4,2,0),B1:B5))
```

Or, in terms of tables:

```
=LET(x,T_1[[#All],[Company]],HSTACK(x,VLOOKUP(x,T_2[#All],2,0),T_1[[#All],[Salesman]]))
```

---

**Google-Sheets:**

[image]

Formula in `G1`:

```
=INDEX({VLOOKUP(A1:A5,D1:E4,{1,2},0),B1:B5})
```

Comment: Sir so neat way you have done, I was doing this `=VSTACK({"Company","Other","Salesman"},CHOOSECOLS(HSTACK(A2:B5,INDEX(E2:E5,XMATCH(A2:A5,D2:D4))),1,3,2))`

Comment: Sir, this one I improvised : `=SORT(HSTACK(A1:B5,INDEX(E1:E4,XMATCH(A1:A5,D1:D4))),{1,2,3},,1)`

Comment: These are good answers and they work in Excel.. Nevertheless, I am actually working in Google Sheets and there is no functions LET, HSTACK. In the original question, I overlooked this detail which turned out very important... Is there a way to implement the same of Google sheets?

Comment: Your whole question is filled with references to Excel. How did you overlook this? @Vitomir, time for you to edit your question.

Comment: @Vitomir Yes you have mentioned in the last line : `Excel` or `VBA`

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
={INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, D2:E, {1, 2}, ))), B2:B}
```

[image]